# Smarty output dynamic variable

Tags: php, variables, smarty

My goal is to assign a dynamic variable (called skill) to a mathematic equation, like this:

```
$skill_HULK = 5, $skill_MAC = 2, ...
```

So I have done this

```
${math assign="skill_`$sk->skill_abbreviation`" equation="x * y" x=1 y=2}
```

where

```
$sk->skill_abbreviation returns HULK and MAC (foreach loop).
```

But how can I output the result of my variable ?
I tried with "eval", but it only show me the name of my variable.
If I do :

```
{eval var="sk_`$sk->skill_abbreviation`"}
```

it will output for example skill_MAC instead of 2.

Can somebody help me please ? Thanks

Comment: I am not a Smarty expert but probably just `{$skill_\`$sk->skill_abbreviation\`}`

Comment: Tried but doesn't work :( Thanks anyway

Comment: `{"$skill_\`$sk->skill_abbreviation\`"|varvar}` ?

Comment: varvar is not implemented, i've only access to theses i guess : https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifiers.tpl
ty!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is this what you're looking for, but please take a look:

PHP:

```
$smarty->assign("skill_abbreviation", "HULK");
$smarty->assign("skill_HULK", 5);
$smarty->assign("skill_MAC", 2);
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

Template:

```
{$skill_{$skill_abbreviation}}
// or
{assign var='myVar' value=$skill_{$skill_abbreviation}}
{$myVar}
```

Result:

```
5
// or
5
```

---

Or you can run this in loop:

PHP:

```
$smarty->assign("skill_abbreviations", ["HULK", "MAC"]);
$smarty->assign("skill_HULK", 5);
$smarty->assign("skill_MAC", 2);
```

Template:

```
{foreach from=$skill_abbreviations item=abbr}
  {$skill_{$abbr}}
{/foreach}
```

Result:

```
  5
  2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! That's not exactly what I'm looking for : I must set a variable into a foreach loop in my template (with the math assign), and must display this variable. So this variable will be skill_HULK, skill_MAC, etc etc and I must display this variable.
I don't know if I explained well sorry for my english
EDIT : I didn't saw your edit sorry ! Yes that's what i'm looking for with your template example (assign), but the name myVar should be dynamic (myVar1, myVar2)

Comment: @AjaxLoser Updated my answer.

Comment: I can't get a result with my project... Maybe let's make it more easy? Like if I have {math assign="sk_"|cat:$i equation="x * y"  x=1 y=2}
I can echo the variable {$sk_0}. But I can't echo the variable {$sk_{$i}} when $i = 0

EDIT : With it, I've this message "syntax error: unrecognized tag: $sk_{$i (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 436) in......"